# SVGKit. NSString to SVGKImage?

Tags: ios, image, nsstring, nsdata, svgkit

SVGKImage has `imageWithData:` method which is not implemented.

I also know that I can store `NSString` object as file and load it to a library via another method. But it would be too slow for me. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: omg. Read question first. `imageWithData:` is not implemented. How `NSString`->`NSData` will help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very strange. They didn't implement `imageWithData:`, but they almost implemented `imageWithString`:

```
#import "SVGKit.h"
#import "SVGKSourceString.h"

NSString *svgStr = ...;
SVGKImage *image = [SVGKImage imageWithSource:[SVGKSourceString sourceFromContentsOfString:svgStr]];
```